# Why is pip installing an old version of my package?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I've just uploaded a new version of my package to PyPi (1.2.1.0-r4): I can download the egg file and install it with easy_install, and the version checks out correctly. But when I try to install using pip, it installs version 1.1.0.0 instead. Even if I explicitly specify the version to pip with `pip install -Iv tome==1.2.1.0-r4`, I get this message: `Requested tome==1.2.1.0-r4, but installing version 1.1.0.0`, but I don't understand why.

I double checked with `parse_version` and confirmed that the version string on 1.2.1 is greater than that on 1.1.0 as shown:

```
>>> from pkg_resources import parse_version as pv
>>> pv('1.1.0.0') < pv('1.2.1.0-r4')
True
>>>
```

So any idea why it's choosing to install 1.1.0 instead?

Comment: Could not reproduce. `pip install -Iv tome==1.2.1.0-r4` installs for me (according to both the messages and `pip freeze` the package `tome==1.2.1.0-r4`.

Comment: It's probably still in your path somewhere? Try it with `-U`

Comment: Hm..alright that's interesting. I've tried uninstalling it with pip, I guess I'll have to dig through some more and make sure it's all gone. Thanks for checking!

Comment: Looks like some kind of bug in pip. I have a similar issue, but I can't install an older version of django-tastypie.

Comment: related, I am having a similar issue with pip install -e https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69303363/why-is-an-old-version-of-a-package-of-my-python-library-installing-by-itself-wit

Answer (score 126, accepted):

This is an excellent question.  It took me forever to figure out.  This is the solution that works for me:

Apparently, if `pip` can find a local version of the package, `pip` will prefer the local versions to remote ones.  I even disconnected my computer from the internet and tried it again -- when `pip` still installed the package successfully, and didn't even complain, the source was obviously local.

The really confusing part, in my case, was that `pip` found the newer versions on [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi), reported them, and then went ahead and re-installed the older version anyway ... arggh.  Also, it didn't tell me what it was doing, and why.

So how did I solve this problem?

You can get `pip` to give verbose output using the `-v` flag ... but one isn't enough.  I RTFM-ed the help, which said you can do `-v` multiple times, up to 3x, for more verbose output.  So I did:

```
pip install -vvv <my_package>
```

Then I looked through the output.  One line caught my eye:

> Source in /tmp/pip-build-root/ has version 0.0.11, which satisfies requirement <my_package>

I deleted that directory, after which `pip` installed the newest version from pypi.

Comment: Looks like this haven't been fixed yet.

Comment: @Ale110 It has been fixed - see my answer for details.

Comment: FYI you can use `-vvv` instead of `-v -v -v`.

Comment: You can also use the `--no-cache-dir` flag instead of hunting down and deleting the file in `/tmp/`.

Comment: doing the pip install in my machine takes ages...how do I find the location of those files? I can see it the pip list but it doesn't point to the path. Any help?

Comment: According to `pip cache -h` output, it should theoretically be possible to do `pip cache remove <my_package>` instead of deleting a `/tmp/...` folder manually; haven't tested that, though - and if `pip` worked as expected, this page wouldn't even exist...

Answer (score 61):

Try forcing download the package again with:

```
pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade <package>
```

Comment: This has worked for me. Finally got v0.4 of photoutils installed over v0.2.1. Pip was downloading v0.4 tar but then it would just install (or keep) the v0.2.1. The --no-cache-dir and --upgrade flags finally did it! Thank you

Comment: This is the right answer here. Pip keeps a cache of the relevant Pypi page for 600 seconds by default. So even if you remove the locally cached package, you've got to wait the 10 minutes for pip to fetch the new page with all the new version links.

Comment: This seems like a very logical answer. However, pip still installs get the same old version, even though the version I see via `pip search` is newer.

Comment: Try checking if it's something with virtualenv. Ah python versions.

Comment: does this work with editable mode e.g. `pip install  -e --no-cache-dir --upgrade ~/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src`?

Comment: is the `--upgrade` needed? (for me I am doing `pip install -e ~/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src`

Answer (score 26):

Thanks to [Marcus Smith](https://github.com/qwcode), who does amazing work as a maintener of pip, this was fixed in version 1.4 of pip which was released on 2013-07-23.

Relevant information from the [changelog](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/news.html#changelog) for this version

> Fixed a number of issues (#413, #709, #634, #602, and #939) related to
>   cleaning up and not reusing build directories. (Pull #865, #948)

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. Upgrade pip like this: ```pip install -U pip```

Comment: This fix still does not address pip silently using a cached version, which can be resolved using Iacchus's answer

Comment: No, it does not seem to be fixed. I'm running into the same problem right now.

Comment: Same here: Ten years on and I am running into the same issue; same problem in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67745900): `--pre` simply doesn't to make any difference when it comes to installing development versions.

Answer (score 17):

I found [here](http://python.6.n6.nabble.com/using-pip-to-install-an-specific-older-version-td4679821.html) that there is a known bug in pip that it won't check the version if there's a build directory with unpacked sources. I have checked this on my troubling package and after deleting its sources from build directory pip installed the required version.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Any idea where I should look for the build directory? I tried deleting it from Python\Lib\site-packages, but the results were the same. I'm not executing the command from a location where the package exists or anything.

Comment: @sh1ftst0rm I'm using virtualenv under linux and for django-tastypie it was that: "$VIRTUAL_ENV/build/django-tastypie". Try to check top of the Python directory or just use search in your system. Also you could try to use "pip install -b <path to custom build dir>".

Comment: This doesn't appear to be my problem, I've searched far and wide and can't find any trace of the package or a build directory for it on my system. It must be some other bug in pip =(. Good tip anyway, I'm sure this will be the fix for a lot of people.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using a `pip` version that comes with some distribution packages (ex. Ubuntu python-pip), you may need to install a newer `pip` version:

Update `pip` to latest version:

```
sudo pip install -U pip
```

In case of "virtualenv", skip "sudo":

```
pip install -U pip
```

Following command may be required, if your shell report something like `-bash: /usr/bin/pip: No such file or directory` after `pip` update:

```
hash -d pip
```

Now install your package as usual:

```
pip install -U foo
```

or

```
pip install foo==package.version.here
```

Answer (score 6):

Got the same issue to update pika 0.9.5 to 0.9.8. The only working way was to install from tarball: `pip install https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pika/pika-0.9.8.tar.gz`.

Comment: +1 Thanks, this clued me into something important: pip relies on source distributions: with my latest version, I forgot to upload a source dist, so when I tried to install, it would only get the previous version. This doesn't solve my original problem, but it's helpful to know.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the python version used (3.4) didn't satisfy Django 2.1 dependencies requirements (python >= 3.5).

Answer (score 1):

For my case I had to delete the `.pip` folder in my home directory and then I was able to get later versions of multiple libraries.  Note that this was on linux.

```
pip --version
pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
virtualenv --version
15.1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I am pip installing a .tar.gz package from Artifactory that I make a lot of updates to. In order to overwrite my cached Python files and always grab/install the latest I was able to run:

```
pip install --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall <path/to/tar.gz>
```

You should see this re-download any necessary files and install those, instead of using your local cache.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case that anyone else hassles with upgrading **torchtext** (or probably any other `torch` library):

Although https://pypi.org/project/torchtext/ states that you could run `pip install torchtext` I had to install it similiar to `torch` by specifying `--find-links` aka `-f`:

```
pip install torchtext===0.8.1 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

What irritated me was that PyCharm pointed me to the new version, but couldn't find it when attempting to upgrade to it. I guess that PyCharm uses its own mechanism to spot new versions. Then, when invoking `pip` under the hood, it didn't find the new version without the `--find-links` option.

Answer (score 1):

10 years on and `pip` still fails to work as expected .

I wasted a couple of hours now banging my head against the wall trying to find out why `pip` won't install a development version of my package. In my case, there are versions `0.0.4` and `0.0.5.dev1` in a private gitlab.com package registry (hence the `--extra-index-url` argument below), but I believe that's not relevant to the problem.

Following a lot of the advice on this page, I create a test venv in a far away folder, clear the pip cache, uninstall the package in question, etc. first to rule out the most common problems:

```
$ pip cache purge && \
  pip uninstall --yes my-package && \
  pip install --extra-index-url "https://_:${GITLAB_PASSWORD_TOOLS_VAULTTOOLS}@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project-id>/packages/pypi/simple" \
              --no-cache-dir  \
              --pre           \
              --upgrade my-package
```

output (using empty lines to separate output for commands):

```
WARNING: No matching packages
Files removed: 0

Found existing installation: my-package 0.0.4
Uninstalling my-package-0.0.4:
  Successfully uninstalled my-package-0.0.4

Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://_:****@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project-id>/packages/pypi/simple
Collecting my-package
  Downloading https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project-id>/packages/pypi/files/f07 ... 397/my_package-0.0.5.dev1-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
  Downloading https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project-id>/packages/pypi/files/775 ... 70e/my_package-0.0.4-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
    ...
Successfully installed my-package-0.0.4
```

So `pip` *does* see the dev package version, but chooses the earlier one nonetheless.

In an attempt to figure out what's going on, I published a `0.0.5` version: Error persists, `pip` sees all three versions, but still installs `0.0.4`.

In a further, increasingly desperate attempt, I removed any versions prior to `0.0.5*` from the gitlab.com package registry.

**Only now**, `pip` would bother to actually display some useful information:

```
$ (same command as above)
    ... (similar output as above) ...
ERROR: Cannot install my-package==0.0.5 and my-package==0.0.5.dev1 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    my-package 0.0.5 depends on my-other-package<0.2.5 and >=0.2.4
    my-package 0.0.5.dev1 depends on my-other-package<0.2.5 and >=0.2.4

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/topics/dependency-resolution/#dealing-with-dependency-conflicts
```

OK, so there is something wrong with my package dependencies. Thanks for letting me know.

Seriously - I tried hard for a couple of hours using all kinds of `pip ... -vvv` and/or fixed versions such as e.g. `my-package==0.0.5.dev1` - but I did not manage to get *any* useful output out of `pip` - until I wiped the entire history from my package registry .

Hope this at least helps someone in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you use microversions, pip doesn't seem to recognize them. For example, we couldn't get version 1.9.9.1 to upgrade.

Comment: maybe because '1.9.9.1' is not SemVer compatible, see https://semver.org/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, someone had published the latest version of a package with python2, so attempting to `pip3 install` it grabbed an older version that *had* been built with python3.

Handy things to check when debugging this:

- If `pip install` claims to not be able to find the version, see whether `pip search` can see it.
- Take a look at the "Download Files" section on the pypi repo -- the filenames might suggest what's wrong (in my case i saw `-py2-` there clear as day).
- As suggested by others, try running `pip install --no-cache-dir` in case pip isn't bothering to ask the internet because it already has your answer locally.

Answer (score 0):

I had hidden unversioned files under the Git tab in PyCharm that were being installed with `pip install .` even though I didn't see the files anywhere else.

Took a long time to find it for me, posting this in hope that it'll help somebody else.

Answer (score 0):

if you need the path for your package do `pip -v list`. Example see related post when using pip -e  [Why is an old version of a package of my python library installing by itself with pip -e?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69303363/why-is-an-old-version-of-a-package-of-my-python-library-installing-by-itself-wit/69304352#69304352)