# pip (1.3.1) not upgrading packages until the local cache is deleted

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to upgrade PACKAGENAME using the following:

```
pip install --index http://pypi.MYSITE.com/simple/ --upgrade PACKAGENAME
```

I often see that no files are downloaded from the server and `pip` says all packages were installed successfully, but when I check the version installed it is **not** the newest version on the server.

However, if I [delete `pip`'s cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510474/removing-pips-cache) and run the above command again, it **does** download files from the server and install the newest version. Has anyone experienced this issue?

One workaround I found is to pass the `--ignore-installed` argument to `pip install`, but this causes `pip` to download all packages from server even if the newest version is already installed.

Comment: please list the pip version in question and platform if possible, pip 1.3.1 has this problem, it hides the error message, pip 1.4 fixed

Comment: I was using pip-1.3.1 and have updated the title.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing pip's cache?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510474/removing-pips-cache)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the issue in pip 1.3.1, I met same problem in Ubuntu 12.10 and Windows, Upgrade to pip 1.4 (so far latest) can solve this problem

There are conflicts in the cache, if you upgrade to 1.4 like using virtualenv if you don't want to update the real environment, you will see the error message.

Answer (score 0):

> (...) if I delete pip's cache (...)

Prior to pip 6.0 you had to pass `--download-cache` option to use [download cache](https://pip.pypa.io/en/1.3.1/logic.html?#download-cache). As you use pip 1.3.1 and you don't pass this option there's nothing in cache.
I suspect what you observe is a bug related to pip (wrongly) reusing build directories. This was fixed in version 1.4 of pip which was released on 2013-07-23. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18105975/95735) to the question *Why is pip installing an old version of my package?* for more details.