# Whoosh ImportError: cannot import name SpellChecker

Tags: django, spell-checking, django-haystack, importerror, whoosh

In order to solve no "FileStorage" attribute problem, I just update the whoosh. However, it comes with this new problem.

```
from whoosh.spelling import SpellChecker
ImportError: cannot import name SpellChecker
```

Answer (score 10):

At the moment, you have to install an older version of Woosh.

```
pip install whoosh==2.4
```

[The issue is in django-haystack.](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/issues/819)

Comment: I get "Requested whoosh==2.4, but installing version 2.5.1"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617136/why-is-pip-installing-an-old-version-of-my-package. pip was using a local copy since I had installed it. So I had to pip uninstall whoosh and then delete the files from the tmp directory.