# Why am I using older (and uninstalled) version of a python numpy package?

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I lost my hope trying to resolve this.
I had the 1.3.0 version of `numpy` installed and I need it to be the latest, so I updated it with:

`pip install --upgrade numpy`

which ended successfully. Then using `print np.__version__` in my code I found out it's still 1.3.0 version. So then I uninstalled `numpy` with `pip` and tried to install it again using [Matt Fenwick's answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617136/why-is-pip-installing-an-old-version-of-my-package) with:

`pip install -v -v -v numpy`

During the installation, which was successful, I got this:

`Using version 1.8.0 (newest of versions: 1.8.0, 1.8.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.1, 1.7.0, 1.7.0, 1.6.2, 1.6.2, 1.6.1, 1.6.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.0, 1.5.1, 1.5.0, 1.4.1, 1.3.0)`

In the `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages` I also see correct package info for a newest version without a hint of 1.3.0.

But `np.__version__ still` gives me 1.3.0! Please help me!

Comment: check the $PATH, type `which python`, use `virtualenv`...look up other threads on this topic: this is probably the most common question I see in the python forum

Comment: Where did `pip` install `numpy` to? What's your `PYTHONPATH`? And what's `np.__path__`?

Comment: @jazzpi they both are `/usr/bin/python2.6/dist-packages`

Comment: @FrauHahnhen, your problem then is that you're importing from the `/usr/bin` installation but upgrading to `/usr/local/lib`.  What do you get from `which pip`?

Comment: @FrauHahnhen: If that's the case, you got some problems... Also, which two?

Comment: @jazzpi `PYTHONPATH` and `np.__path__`. @askewchan is right, I missaw the upgrating directory name... Must have gone blind in the end of the day. Thanks!

Comment: Does that mean you've solved the problem, @FrauHahnhen?

Answer (score -1):

Check to see if your version is still 1.3.0 or not. Use this code:

```
import python
python.__version__
```

If it shows '1.3.0', you have to first delete the numpy package from:

```
virtualenv_name/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

If you are using virtual environment and if you are installing numpy on core go to:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
```

Now download the latest numpy package by:

```
sudo pip install numpy==1.7.1 --upgrade
```

Now move this folder to the above mentioned place as according to the situation.
It worked for me.

Hope this will work for you too.