# Pip doesn't install latest GitHub release

Tags: git, pip

I have two releases tagged on GitHub: 0.1 and 0.2. When I manually download `https://github.com/username/repo/tarball/master`, version 0.2 gets downloaded. However, if I do `pip install https://github.com/username/repo/tarball/master` in my command line, version 0.1 get installed. Why is this happening? How can I install my repo's latest release via Pip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the issue was something much, much silly. I forgot to update the package's version in `setup.py` to 0.2, so it was installing 0.1, even though the code was the one updated for 0.2.

The conclusion is: don't forget to check&update your package's version in `setup.py`!

If this isn't the case, then try @JavaCake's solution.

Answer (score 1):

When this happens i usually do following:

1. Create a text file with a requirement for pip specifying the git repo and the commit hashtag.
2. Use `pip install` with [requirement option](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#pip-install).

**Eg:**

requirement.txt:

```
git+git://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps.git@5d7705bc32b3eab042790dc26ffa1a1c81844438
```

from bash:

```
pip install -r requirement.txt
```

Comment: I know, but since releases are, well, released, very often, I don't want to change my requirements file. I would like Pip to be able to fetch the latest release from GitHub.

Comment: What happens when you use `upgrade` parameter? Also have you updated pip?

Comment: Also check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617136/why-is-pip-installing-an-old-version-of-my-package

Comment: Can you try and install in verbose mode and see what it does? It may be attempting to install the local version all the time instead of looking for a (newer) remote..

Comment: After further digging, I think this is the case. But manually deleting the folder where Pip unpacks packages isn't a solution...

Comment: Does it redownload the old version from remote again?

Comment: No, but as I said, I don't want to manually delete that folder each time I need to install my reqs...

Comment: Alright, it seems the problem was something else. I forgot to bump the version in my setup.py which I've uploaded to GitHub, so it was always showing 0.1, even if the code was the one updated for 0.2...Very silly, but thank you for helping me!