# pip install latest release from GitHub

Tags: python, github, pip

I know I can install the master branch with:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/USER/REPO
```

I also know I can install a specific release with:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/USER/REPO@RELEASE
```

But is there a way to install the latest release (the one GitHub returns at https://github.com/USER/REPO/releases/latest)? I've tried the following:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/USER/REPO@latest
```

but it fails:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: git checkout -q latest
```

---

EDIT: This question is not a duplicate of [Pip doesn't install latest GitHub release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20814857/pip-doesnt-install-latest-github-release). The latter is about how to install a specific release and/or from the master branch, but not from the latest release.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pip doesn't install latest GitHub release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20814857/pip-doesnt-install-latest-github-release)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the github API. Something like

```
pip install "git+https://github.com/USER/REPO@$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/USER/REPO/releases/latest | jq -r ".tag_name")"
```

would probably work for you. If you don't feel like installing jq, there's e.g. [this gist](https://gist.github.com/lukechilds/a83e1d7127b78fef38c2914c4ececc3c).

Answer (score 1):

This might be a bad idea, but you can grab the latest tarball url from GitHub's rest API:

```sh
pip install \
 $(python3 -c "import urllib.request, json, sys; \
 u=json.loads(urllib.request.urlopen('https://api.github.com/repos/USER/REPO/releases/latest').read().decode()).get('tarball_url', False);\
 print(u) if u else sys.exit(1);")
```

Which you drop into `pip install` using command substitution `$(..)`

There should be a couple of options available, either `tarball_url` and `zipball_url` and pip should be able to download these.