# How to run a script or a ipython notebook running based on a repository of codes that is cloned from github, rather than the conda package version

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, github, conda

I rather have a simplistic question (due to my ignorance). I have a certain package that is available as a conda download. This package is for fluid flow simulation. Recently the developers have updated few functions within it and has uploaded the codes on github, but has not updated the conda package.

I want to set up my script based on this new github repository. How can I do it so that the cloned repository does not mess up with the conda package? I appreciate your guidance with this.

Comment: Use a virtual environment and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68315468/pip-install-latest-release-from-github

Comment: If you need more help, please indicate where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Hi, Thanks @trplee for your help. It worked.