# Why can't pip install the latest version of deap?

Tags: python, pip, deap

Pypi says [there is a new version on their website](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/deap/1.0.2).

`pip search` tells me I have an old version and there is a new one.

```
(Canopy 64bit) Johns-iMac:~ john$ pip search deap
deap                      - Distributed Evolutionary Algorithms in Python
 INSTALLED: 1.0.1
 LATEST:    1.0.2
```

But `pip install -U` with all the overrides says there is no new version.

```
(Canopy 64bit) Johns-iMac:~ john$ pip install -U --allow-unverified --allow-external deap==1.0.2
Collecting deap==1.0.2
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement deap==1.0.2 (from versions: 0.9.1, 0.9.2, 1.0.0rc3, 1.0.0, 1.0.1)
No distributions matching the version for deap==1.0.2
```

What silly detail am I overlooking?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is pip installing an old version of my package?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617136/why-is-pip-installing-an-old-version-of-my-package)

Comment: Bit sad when I have to vote to close my own question.  The "related" suggestions are so much more useful than trying to hit exactly the right keywords via the search.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same behavior. If you don't need necessarily stable release you can install from home repository https://github.com/DEAP/deap

```
pip install git+https://github.com/DEAP/deap

pip search deap
deap                      - Distributed Evolutionary Algorithms in Python
INSTALLED: 1.1.0
LATEST:    1.0.2
```