# Why is pip installing an older version of this package?

Tags: python, pip

I have read [Why is pip installing an old version of my package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617136/why-is-pip-installing-an-old-version-of-my-package) and followed the second answer but either

```
pip install mistune
```

or

```
pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade mistune
```

installs `mistune-0.8.4` whereas a newer version is available:

```
pip install mistune==2.0.0a4
```

**Why does this happen?**

Comment: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#pre-release-versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [package's version history](https://pypi.org/project/mistune/#history), 0.8.4 is the most current released version, while those newer version are prereleases, and will not be downloaded by default.

Comment: What Is the general rule that `pip` uses? is this "pre-release" mention a "tag" that can be set on each package of Pypi?

Comment: @Basj https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#pre-releases