# Pip install not matching a development version of a package

Tags: python, pip

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement my-package==2021.4.* (from versions: 0.0.2, 2021.4.1.dev44+gd452819a91.d20210528, 2021.5.26)
```

This looks weird, right? Why doesn't the second one in the list match???
`~=2021.4.1` doesn't work either. `=~2021.4` installs `2021.5.26`

The only way I found for it to work is to spell it out completely: `==2021.4.1.dev44+gd452819a91.d20210528`

Why don't the match operators work?

Comment: Did you find a solution to that problem? I do have the same issue

Comment: Yeah ... My solution was to stop trying to do anything with python and stick to normal languages :) Never looked back!

Comment: I had the same issue, for me appending `>=-`; i.e.,  running `python -m pip install "[packaage-name]>=-" -f [dist-folder]` worked

Answer (score 3):

By default, pip ignores pre-release and development versions. Per the pip documentation on [pre-release versions](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#pre-release-versions):

> Starting with v1.4, pip will only install stable versions as specified by [pre-releases](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/#handling-of-pre-releases) by default. If a version cannot be parsed as a compliant [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440) version then it is assumed to be a pre-release.
>
> If a Requirement specifier includes a pre-release or development version (e.g. `>=0.0.dev0`) then pip will allow pre-release and development versions for that requirement. This does not include the != flag.

If you want pip to also match pre-release and development version against the version specifier, you can pass the [`--pre`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-pre) flag when invoking `pip install`:

Comment: Tried running it with `--pre` - did not seem to make any difference :(