# Why is an old version of a package of my python library installing by itself with pip -e?

Tags: python, pip

I was installing my ultimate-utils package in editable mode but whenver I do that it seems to install an old version of it by itself.

I did see this question: [Why is pip installing an old version of my package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617136/why-is-pip-installing-an-old-version-of-my-package)

but thought it would still be interesting to ask since although re-installing things might work e.g. with

```
pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -e ~/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src
```

or

```
pip install -vvv -e ~/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src
```

in my HPC it's an expensive operation to do pip installs. So it would be good to see how to find the old version of the library and delete it locally if it's using that for the install.

See:

```
(synthesis) miranda9~/type-parametric-synthesis $ pip list
Package                               Version      Location
------------------------------------- ------------ -----------------------------------------------------
absl-py                               0.14.0
...
ultimate-utils                        0.2.0        /home/miranda9/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src
...                             1.26.7
uutils                                0.1.0
...
```

there should be no uutils in the pip list I believe and it should definitively not be 0.1.0. How do I have pip stop doing this or find the uutils location and delete it?

I greped the install output but it doesn't even mentions uutils!

```
(synthesis) miranda9~/type-parametric-synthesis $ pip install -e ~/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src

Obtaining file:///home/miranda9/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src
Requirement already satisfied: torch==1.9.1 in /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/synthesis/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from ultimate-utils==0.2.0) (1.9.1+cu111)
Requirement already satisfied: torchvision==0.10.1 in /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/synthesis/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from ultimate-utils==0.2.0) (0.10.1+cu111)
Requirement already satisfied: torchaudio==0.9.1 in /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/synthesis/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from ultimate-utils==0.2.0) (0.9.1)
Collecting dill
  Using cached dill-0.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (86 kB)
Collecting networkx>=2.5
  Using cached networkx-2.6.3-py3-none-any.whl (1.9 MB)
Collecting scipy
  Using cached scipy-1.7.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.whl (28.5 MB)
Collecting scikit-learn
  Using cached scikit_learn-0.24.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (23.8 MB)
Collecting lark-parser
  Using cached lark_parser-0.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (103 kB)
Collecting torchtext>=0.8.1
  Using cached torchtext-0.10.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (7.6 MB)
Collecting tensorboard
  Using cached tensorboard-2.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (5.6 MB)
Collecting pandas
  Using cached pandas-1.3.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (11.5 MB)
Collecting progressbar2
  Using cached progressbar2-3.53.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting transformers
  Using cached transformers-4.10.3-py3-none-any.whl (2.8 MB)
Collecting requests
  Using cached requests-2.26.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (62 kB)
Collecting aiohttp
  Using cached aiohttp-3.7.4.post0-cp39-cp39-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.4 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/synthesis/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from ultimate-utils==0.2.0) (1.21.2)
Collecting plotly
  Using cached plotly-5.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23.9 MB)
Collecting wandb
  Using cached wandb-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.7 MB)
Collecting matplotlib
  Using cached matplotlib-3.4.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (10.3 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: typing-extensions in /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/synthesis/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from torch==1.9.1->ultimate-utils==0.2.0) (3.10.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=5.3.0 in /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/synthesis/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from torchvision==0.10.1->ultimate-utils==0.2.0) (8.3.2)
Collecting tqdm
  Using cached tqdm-4.62.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0
  Using cached yarl-1.6.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (315 kB)
Collecting attrs>=17.3.0
  Using cached attrs-21.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
Collecting chardet<5.0,>=2.0
  Using cached chardet-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (178 kB)
Collecting async-timeout<4.0,>=3.0
  Using cached async_timeout-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (8.2 kB)
Collecting multidict<7.0,>=4.5
  Using cached multidict-5.1.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (151 kB)
Collecting idna>=2.0
  Using cached idna-3.2-py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
Collecting pyparsing>=2.2.1
  Using cached pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting cycler>=0.10
  Using cached cycler-0.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.5 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.7
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
Collecting kiwisolver>=1.0.1
  Using cached kiwisolver-1.3.2-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (1.6 MB)
Collecting six
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting pytz>=2017.3
  Using cached pytz-2021.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (510 kB)
Collecting tenacity>=6.2.0
  Using cached tenacity-8.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting python-utils>=2.3.0
  Using cached python_utils-2.5.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/synthesis/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests->ultimate-utils==0.2.0) (2021.5.30)
Collecting urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1
  Using cached urllib3-1.26.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
Collecting charset-normalizer~=2.0.0
  Using cached charset_normalizer-2.0.6-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting threadpoolctl>=2.0.0
  Using cached threadpoolctl-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting joblib>=0.11
  Using cached joblib-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (303 kB)
Collecting google-auth<2,>=1.6.3
  Using cached google_auth-1.35.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (152 kB)
Collecting google-auth-oauthlib<0.5,>=0.4.1
  Using cached google_auth_oauthlib-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting tensorboard-plugin-wit>=1.6.0
  Using cached tensorboard_plugin_wit-1.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (781 kB)
Collecting werkzeug>=0.11.15
  Using cached Werkzeug-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (288 kB)
Collecting tensorboard-data-server<0.7.0,>=0.6.0
  Using cached tensorboard_data_server-0.6.1-py3-none-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (4.9 MB)
Collecting protobuf>=3.6.0
  Using cached protobuf-3.18.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.1 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/synthesis/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from tensorboard->ultimate-utils==0.2.0) (0.37.0)
Collecting markdown>=2.6.8
  Using cached Markdown-3.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting grpcio>=1.24.3
  Using cached grpcio-1.40.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (4.3 MB)
Collecting absl-py>=0.4
  Using cached absl_py-0.14.0-py3-none-any.whl (131 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=41.0.0 in /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/synthesis/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from tensorboard->ultimate-utils==0.2.0) (58.0.4)
Collecting cachetools<5.0,>=2.0.0
  Using cached cachetools-4.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting rsa<5,>=3.1.4
  Using cached rsa-4.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
Collecting pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1
  Using cached pyasn1_modules-0.2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (155 kB)
Collecting requests-oauthlib>=0.7.0
  Using cached requests_oauthlib-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Collecting pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6
  Using cached pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
Collecting oauthlib>=3.0.0
  Using cached oauthlib-3.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (146 kB)
Collecting filelock
  Using cached filelock-3.0.12-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Collecting regex!=2019.12.17
  Using cached regex-2021.8.28-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (759 kB)
Collecting sacremoses
  Using cached sacremoses-0.0.45-py3-none-any.whl (895 kB)
Collecting huggingface-hub>=0.0.12
  Using cached huggingface_hub-0.0.17-py3-none-any.whl (52 kB)
Collecting packaging
  Using cached packaging-21.0-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
Collecting pyyaml>=5.1
  Using cached PyYAML-5.4.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (630 kB)
Collecting tokenizers<0.11,>=0.10.1
  Using cached tokenizers-0.10.3-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (3.3 MB)
Collecting click
  Using cached click-8.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
Collecting sentry-sdk>=1.0.0
  Using cached sentry_sdk-1.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (139 kB)
Collecting docker-pycreds>=0.4.0
  Using cached docker_pycreds-0.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.0 kB)
Collecting promise<3,>=2.0
  Using cached promise-2.3-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting yaspin>=1.0.0
  Using cached yaspin-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting configparser>=3.8.1
  Using cached configparser-5.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting GitPython>=1.0.0
  Using cached GitPython-3.1.24-py3-none-any.whl (180 kB)
Collecting psutil>=5.0.0
  Using cached psutil-5.8.0-cp39-cp39-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (293 kB)
Collecting shortuuid>=0.5.0
  Using cached shortuuid-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.5 kB)
Collecting subprocess32>=3.5.3
  Using cached subprocess32-3.5.4-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pathtools
  Using cached pathtools-0.1.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting gitdb<5,>=4.0.1
  Using cached gitdb-4.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (63 kB)
Collecting smmap<5,>=3.0.1
  Using cached smmap-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting termcolor<2.0.0,>=1.1.0
  Using cached termcolor-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: urllib3, pyasn1, idna, charset-normalizer, smmap, six, rsa, requests, pyparsing, pyasn1-modules, oauthlib, cachetools, tqdm, termcolor, requests-oauthlib, regex, packaging, multidict, joblib, google-auth, gitdb, filelock, click, yaspin, yarl, werkzeug, tokenizers, threadpoolctl, tensorboard-plugin-wit, tensorboard-data-server, tenacity, subprocess32, shortuuid, sentry-sdk, scipy, sacremoses, pyyaml, pytz, python-utils, python-dateutil, psutil, protobuf, promise, pathtools, markdown, kiwisolver, huggingface-hub, grpcio, google-auth-oauthlib, GitPython, docker-pycreds, cycler, configparser, chardet, attrs, async-timeout, absl-py, wandb, transformers, torchtext, tensorboard, scikit-learn, progressbar2, plotly, pandas, networkx, matplotlib, lark-parser, dill, aiohttp, ultimate-utils
  Running setup.py develop for ultimate-utils
Successfully installed GitPython-3.1.24 absl-py-0.14.0 aiohttp-3.7.4.post0 async-timeout-3.0.1 attrs-21.2.0 cachetools-4.2.2 chardet-4.0.0 charset-normalizer-2.0.6 click-8.0.1 configparser-5.0.2 cycler-0.10.0 dill-0.3.4 docker-pycreds-0.4.0 filelock-3.0.12 gitdb-4.0.7 google-auth-1.35.0 google-auth-oauthlib-0.4.6 grpcio-1.40.0 huggingface-hub-0.0.17 idna-3.2 joblib-1.0.1 kiwisolver-1.3.2 lark-parser-0.12.0 markdown-3.3.4 matplotlib-3.4.3 multidict-5.1.0 networkx-2.6.3 oauthlib-3.1.1 packaging-21.0 pandas-1.3.3 pathtools-0.1.2 plotly-5.3.1 progressbar2-3.53.3 promise-2.3 protobuf-3.18.0 psutil-5.8.0 pyasn1-0.4.8 pyasn1-modules-0.2.8 pyparsing-2.4.7 python-dateutil-2.8.2 python-utils-2.5.6 pytz-2021.1 pyyaml-5.4.1 regex-2021.8.28 requests-2.26.0 requests-oauthlib-1.3.0 rsa-4.7.2 sacremoses-0.0.45 scikit-learn-0.24.2 scipy-1.7.1 sentry-sdk-1.4.1 shortuuid-1.0.1 six-1.16.0 smmap-4.0.0 subprocess32-3.5.4 tenacity-8.0.1 tensorboard-2.6.0 tensorboard-data-server-0.6.1 tensorboard-plugin-wit-1.8.0 termcolor-1.1.0 threadpoolctl-2.2.0 tokenizers-0.10.3 torchtext-0.10.1 tqdm-4.62.3 transformers-4.10.3 ultimate-utils-0.2.0 urllib3-1.26.7 wandb-0.12.2 werkzeug-2.0.1 yarl-1.6.3 yaspin-2.1.0
(synthesis) miranda9~/type-parametric-synthesis $
```

very mysterious!

You should be able to install uutils with `pip install ultimate-utils` but I believe the issue is a pip install -e issue...

Comment: try `pip -v list` to see where the redundant library is pointing to (if in editable they are likely the same)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why it didn't occur to me to do a verbose pip list but I did it and it says that both `ultimate-utils` and `uutils` point to the same place. Very confusing but alright, idk why pip install uutils and has it say 0.1.0 but it doesn't show its an editable path like the other one:

```
(metalearning_gpu) miranda9~/automl-meta-learning $ pip -v list
Package                 Version      Location                                                                    Installer
----------------------- ------------ --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ---------
absl-py                 0.14.0       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
aiohttp                 3.7.4.post0  /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
async-timeout           3.0.1        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
attrs                   21.2.0       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
cachetools              4.2.2        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
certifi                 2021.5.30    /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages
chardet                 4.0.0        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
charset-normalizer      2.0.6        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
click                   8.0.1        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
configparser            5.0.2        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
cycler                  0.10.0       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
dill                    0.3.4        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
docker-pycreds          0.4.0        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
filelock                3.0.12       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
gitdb                   4.0.7        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
GitPython               3.1.24       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
google-auth             1.35.0       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
google-auth-oauthlib    0.4.6        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
grpcio                  1.40.0       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
huggingface-hub         0.0.17       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
idna                    3.2          /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
joblib                  1.0.1        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
kiwisolver              1.3.2        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
lark-parser             0.12.0       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
Markdown                3.3.4        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
matplotlib              3.4.3        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
multidict               5.1.0        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
networkx                2.6.3        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
numpy                   1.21.2       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
oauthlib                3.1.1        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
packaging               21.0         /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
pandas                  1.3.3        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
pathtools               0.1.2        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
Pillow                  8.3.2        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
pip                     21.2.4       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages
plotly                  5.3.1        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
progressbar2            3.53.3       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
promise                 2.3          /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
protobuf                3.18.0       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
psutil                  5.8.0        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
pyasn1                  0.4.8        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
pyasn1-modules          0.2.8        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
pyparsing               2.4.7        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
python-dateutil         2.8.2        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
python-utils            2.5.6        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
pytz                    2021.1       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
PyYAML                  5.4.1        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
regex                   2021.8.28    /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
requests                2.26.0       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
requests-oauthlib       1.3.0        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
rsa                     4.7.2        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
sacremoses              0.0.45       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
scikit-learn            0.24.2       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
scipy                   1.7.1        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
sentry-sdk              1.4.1        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
setuptools              58.0.4       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages
shortuuid               1.0.1        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
six                     1.16.0       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
smmap                   4.0.0        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
subprocess32            3.5.4        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
tenacity                8.0.1        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
tensorboard             2.6.0        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
tensorboard-data-server 0.6.1        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
tensorboard-plugin-wit  1.8.0        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
termcolor               1.1.0        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
threadpoolctl           2.2.0        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
tokenizers              0.10.3       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
torch                   1.9.1+cu111  /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
torchaudio              0.9.1        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
torchtext               0.10.1       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
torchvision             0.10.1+cu111 /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
tqdm                    4.62.3       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
transformers            4.10.3       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
typing-extensions       3.10.0.2     /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
ultimate-utils          0.3.0        /home/miranda9/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src
urllib3                 1.26.7       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
uutils                  0.1.0        /home/miranda9/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src
wandb                   0.12.2       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
Werkzeug                2.0.1        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
wheel                   0.37.0       /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages
yarl                    1.6.3        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
yaspin                  2.1.0        /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/metalearning_gpu/lib/python3.9/site-packages pip
```

in particular:

```
ultimate-utils          0.3.0        /home/miranda9/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src
...
uutils                  0.1.0        /home/miranda9/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src
```

I guess this is fine if we are installing things in editable mode as long as they point to the same place.

---

fyi, I did try to do pip -vvv but when I grep the file it didn't show any sign of uutils in it...

---

Note there are no issues when installed with pypi and pip

```
pip install ultimate-utils
```

then check it, no redudant uutils:

```
(uutils_env) miranda9~/type-parametric-synthesis $ pip list
Package                 Version
----------------------- -----------
absl-py                 0.14.0
aiohttp                 3.7.4.post0
async-timeout           3.0.1
attrs                   21.2.0
cachetools              4.2.2
certifi                 2021.5.30
chardet                 4.0.0
charset-normalizer      2.0.6
click                   8.0.1
configparser            5.0.2
cycler                  0.10.0
dill                    0.3.4
docker-pycreds          0.4.0
filelock                3.0.12
gitdb                   4.0.7
GitPython               3.1.24
google-auth             1.35.0
google-auth-oauthlib    0.4.6
grpcio                  1.40.0
huggingface-hub         0.0.17
idna                    3.2
joblib                  1.0.1
kiwisolver              1.3.2
lark-parser             0.12.0
Markdown                3.3.4
matplotlib              3.4.3
multidict               5.1.0
networkx                2.6.3
numpy                   1.21.2
oauthlib                3.1.1
packaging               21.0
pandas                  1.3.3
pathtools               0.1.2
Pillow                  8.3.2
pip                     21.2.4
plotly                  5.3.1
progressbar2            3.53.3
promise                 2.3
protobuf                3.18.0
psutil                  5.8.0
pyasn1                  0.4.8
pyasn1-modules          0.2.8
pyparsing               2.4.7
python-dateutil         2.8.2
python-utils            2.5.6
pytz                    2021.1
PyYAML                  5.4.1
regex                   2021.8.28
requests                2.26.0
requests-oauthlib       1.3.0
rsa                     4.7.2
sacremoses              0.0.45
scikit-learn            0.24.2
scipy                   1.7.1
sentry-sdk              1.4.1
setuptools              58.0.4
shortuuid               1.0.1
six                     1.16.0
smmap                   4.0.0
subprocess32            3.5.4
tenacity                8.0.1
tensorboard             2.6.0
tensorboard-data-server 0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit  1.8.0
termcolor               1.1.0
threadpoolctl           2.2.0
tokenizers              0.10.3
torch                   1.9.1
torchaudio              0.9.1
torchtext               0.10.1
torchvision             0.10.1
tqdm                    4.62.3
transformers            4.10.3
typing-extensions       3.10.0.2
ultimate-utils          0.3.0
urllib3                 1.26.7
wandb                   0.12.2
Werkzeug                2.0.1
wheel                   0.37.0
yarl                    1.6.3
yaspin                  2.1.0
```