# How to install Astropy 5.0 using pip?

Tags: python, astropy

I am trying to install Astropy 5.0. As the [docs](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/install.html)

```
pip install astropy
```

checking version:

```
import astropy
astropy.__version__
```

result:

```
'4.3.1'
```

I also try:

```
!pip install astropy==5.0
```

and

```
!pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir astropy==5.0
```

both leading to the error message:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement astropy==5.0 (from versions: 0.1, 0.2, 0.2.1, 0.2.2, 0.2.3, 0.2.4, 0.2.5, 0.3, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.4rc1, 0.4rc2, 0.4, 0.4.1, 0.4.2, 0.4.3, 0.4.4, 0.4.5, 0.4.6, 1.0rc1, 1.0rc2, 1.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.0.9, 1.0.10, 1.0.11, 1.0.12, 1.0.13, 1.1b1, 1.1rc1, 1.1rc2, 1.1, 1.1.post1, 1.1.post2, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2rc1, 1.2, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.3rc1, 1.3, 1.3.1, 1.3.2, 1.3.3, 2.0rc1, 2.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9, 2.0.10, 2.0.11, 2.0.12, 2.0.13, 2.0.14, 2.0.15, 2.0.16, 3.0rc1, 3.0rc2, 3.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.0.4, 3.0.5, 3.1rc1, 3.1rc2, 3.1, 3.1.1, 3.1.2, 3.2rc1, 3.2rc2, 3.2, 3.2.1, 3.2.2, 3.2.3, 4.0rc1, 4.0rc2, 4.0, 4.0.1, 4.0.1.post1, 4.0.2, 4.0.3, 4.0.4, 4.0.5, 4.0.6.dev27461, 4.0.6, 4.1rc1, 4.1rc2, 4.1, 4.2rc1, 4.2, 4.2.1, 4.3rc1, 4.3, 4.3.post1, 4.3.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for astropy==5.0
```

It seems that pip is unaware of an 5.0 version of Astropy. I also do:

```
pip --version
```

Output:

```
pip 21.3.1 from /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

which seems to be the latest version, but I update anyway as suggested [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/):

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pip in /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages (21.3.1)
```

**How do I install Astropy 5.0 using pip?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your `pip --version` output:

```
pip 21.3.1 from /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

you are using Python 3.7, but Astropy 5.0 requires Python 3.8 at a minimum:

https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/changelog.html#other-changes-and-additions

Though this probably also should have been made more clear in [What's New in Astropy 5.0](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/whatsnew/5.0.html).

Answer (score -1):

If the requirement is already satisfied then it must already be installed. You have tried reinstalling it but you can try uninstalling it...

```
pip uninstall astropy
```

Or maybe reinstall pip altogether along with your python installation if the error persists.

Answer (score -1):

**pip priorities installing from locally when it is available locally and remotely.** Try removing all the files from file system containing that file.
[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617136/why-is-pip-installing-an-old-version-of-my-package) may help you.