# Cannot install django 1.4 error

Tags: python, django

When I try install django 1.4 it gives me 1.5:

```
imac9:site-packages pdadmin$ sudo pip install django==1.4.1
Downloading/unpacking django==1.4.1
  Running setup.py egg_info for package django

    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found under directory '*'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.py[co]' found under directory '*'
  Requested django==1.4.1, but installing version 1.5.1
Installing collected packages: django
    Found existing installation: Django 1.5.1
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957766/how-to-install-django-1-4

Answer (score 2):

You might already have a more recent version.

`Found existing installation: Django 1.5.1`

I guess you should uninstall that one first.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv). That way your 1.4 and 1.5 installs can coexist peacefully in separate environments (it's nicer for distribution/deployment anyway). I'm running 1.4.1 and 1.5 in two separate projects at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to get around this was to download the 1.4 tar and manually install it.