# The smallest python distribtion to run Sympy, Scipy, Numpy and Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy

**Update:** 
I tried @user2258766 suggestion on miniconda. It was initially very promising. But, when I have installed scipy numpy matplotlib sympy, the miniconda folder size quickly grows to 1G.

[image]

Does this mean that the minimal size of the installation is 1G if I want to use the 4 packages I mentioned. Why they are so large? Is it still possible to shrink the installation size further?

[image]

--

The Scipy website recommended Anaconda.

But it installs so many un-relevant packages for me.

Is there a smallest distribution I can use?

I only want Scipy, Sympy, Numpy, and Maplotlib, not others.

Another relevant questions is, why there are so many dependencies between these Python packages?

I was programming in Java, and now feel a little bit uncomfortable to see these Python packages (Scipy e.g.) are so tightly relatively to so many other packages. Why is that the case? A reasonable explanation could possible make more comfortable to start coding in Python.

Thanks.

I am using Windows. Thanks. I was using Java and am new to Python.

Comment: Why not just download Python itself and install the only libraries you need?

Comment: The [official scipy site](http://www.scipy.org/install.html#individual-binary-and-source-packages) has a list of individual binaries (all of the ones you give are listed).  Follow each link and download each package individually.  Alternatively, you could use [easy_install](http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/easy_install.html).

Comment: i bet conda is saving the archived libraries so that you won't need to download them again in the event that you create different but similar environment

Comment: @PaulH Thanks for the suggestion. I am not sure whether that is the case. I am just a little bit disappointed for my first try in Python. Maybe I should just accept it that Python should be at least 1G to work for me. Such a pity. Maybe I should re-consider whether I should change from my current Java+Gnuplot+maxima to Python.

Comment: you can surely clear out that cache, manually or otherwise

Comment: `conda clean -a` should remove about 100-300 MB of unused tar.bz2 archive files. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241133/how-to-reduce-the-number-of-files-in-the-anaconda-directory

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest downloading miniconda: http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html#miniconda.  Miniconda has a small footprint -- only python and conda are installed.  Conda is a universal package manager for Python available on all OSes.  You can now run the following:

```
conda create -n dev_env scipy numpy matplotlib sympy
```

The above will create a contained environment (named dev_env) with only the packages listed in the command.  For more information on conda: http://conda.pydata.org/

Comment: I tried miniconda. It was initially very promising. But, when I have installed scipy numpy matplotlib sympy, the miniconda folder size quickly grows to 1G. While the full Anaconda-1.9.2 is 1.3G after installation. ... ...

Comment: Hmm, that seems odd.  I just tired this and my directory is reasonable 237M /Users/quasiben/anaconda/envs/dev_env/

Comment: That means, I must have done something wrong...But there are only two steps right. 1) install miniconda, 2) run the command you give me "conda create -n dev_env scipy numpy matplotlib sympy". I can not be wrong, can I?

Comment: The initial size of the Miniconda is small: 64MB before running "conda create".

Comment: @Leo, you are correct.  I apologize for my somewhat glib remark earlier.  I can confirm the size of the installed pkgs does bring the total size to +1GB.  You can reduce the footprint a bit by calling `conda clean --tarballs` and `conda clean --packages`.  This reduced my footprint to 500MB which is expected.  SciPy is ~200MB Numpy: ~100MB PySide: ~200MB...

Comment: Maybe whatever you are using to measure the size is counting hardlinks twice. Conda installs packages by unpacking the tarballs in the `pkgs` directory and then hard linking them to the install environment. Hard links take up no additional hard disk space, but a naive method of counting hard disk space will count the same file multiple times.

Answer (score 5):

Use these commands to reduce the install size of Python libraries, by removing unnecessary downloaded package files:

```
# Remove about 100-300 MB of unused tar.bz2 archive files
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241133
conda clean --all

# Manually delete about 1-2GB of downloaded packages, after install. See:
# https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/d/msg/anaconda/CZjcQKVmIgo/Xx3tYBYzCgAJ
du -sh /path/to/Miniconda/pkgs/  # Just display the folder size
rm -rf /path/to/Miniconda/pkgs/

# Manually delete the useless Pip cache of downloaded files. See:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510474/removing-pips-cache
rm -rf ~/.cache/pip           # Linux
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/pip/  # Mac OS X
del %LocalAppData%\pip\Cache  # Windows
```

Direct links for info:

- [How to reduce the number of files in the anaconda directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241133/how-to-reduce-the-number-of-files-in-the-anaconda-directory)
- https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/d/msg/anaconda/CZjcQKVmIgo/Xx3tYBYzCgAJ
- [Removing pip's cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510474/removing-pips-cache)

Answer (score 2):

Just install python and individually install each library.

This site has windows installers for all the packages you mentioned:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: It's worth noting that `matplotlib` has several dependencies that also need to be installed, plus several other optional ones, depending on what you're using it for.