# Forcing `pip` to recompile a previously installed package (numpy) after switching to a different Python binary

Tags: python, numpy, installation, pip, virtualenv

This question is as much a question about my particular problem (which I sort of found a work-around, so it's not a burning issue) as it is about the general process I am using.

---

#### Setup (the part that works):

I have Python 2.7.9 installed locally on my Ubuntu 14.04, and I have a virtualenv in which I am running it. Everything is very much separated from the "system" Python, which I am not touching.

---

#### The part I did:

It all started well enough, with my Python installed and all libraries running. For example, I also `pip` installed numpy 1.10.1, it compiled for a while, then it worked just fine.

#### The problem:

The problem is that for reasons beyond my control, I had to rebuild the python with `ucs4` enabled, that is I installed it using

```
./configure --enable-unicode=ucs4
```

After doing this, I also uninstalled all libraries and reinstalled them using pip. However, it seems that the numpy library was not properly uninstalled because it installed instantly this time, and when I tried to import `numpy` into my new Python, I got an error message indicating that the numpy was compiled with the `ucs2`-enabled Python.

This hypothesis is pretty solid, since I tried then to `pip install numpy==1.9.3`. The installation once again took a long time, and it produced a numpy version *that works on the new `ucs4` enabled Python*.

#### Now, my question:

> How can I get the numpy uninstallation process to delete all traces of the old numpy?

---

*Edit*:

I also tried to manually remove numpy by deleting it from my virtualenv `site-packages` directory. After deleting, `import numpy` returned an `ImportError` as expected. I then reinstalled it (`pip install numpy`) and it came back with the same `ucs2`-related error.

*Edit 2*:

The full `sys.path` seen by my virtualenv Python is

```
['',
 '/home/jkralj/.virtualenvs/work/lib/python27.zip',
 '/home/jkralj/.virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/jkralj/.virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/jkralj/.virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/jkralj/.virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/jkralj/.virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/jkralj/.virtualenvs/work/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Also, it might be important to mention that the `/usr/local/lib/python2.7.9/` installation of python **does not** have numpy installed.

Comment: @ali_m I tried that,  but it did not work.

Comment: @ali_m no, check the edit I wrote. It did not work in that it did uninstall numpy, but reinstalling it brought the same error back. Also, `which python` prints the virtualenv python

Comment: @ali_m Your hypothesis does not explain the fact that installing numpy 1.9.3 works just fine.

Comment: @ali_m I edited my question some more.

Comment: @ali_m As I said, "I then reinstalled it (`pip install numpy`) and it came back with the same error."

Comment: @ali_m It worked! `pip install -v numpy` showed that it was istalling numpy out of a cached `whl` file it had build with the old python (`vcs2` enabled). Running `pip install numpy --no-cache-dir` forced `pip` to install anew, and it recompiled numpy into something that actually works.

Comment: @ali_m Thank you so much for all your help. If you post any kind of answer to this question, I will gladly accept it...

Comment: No, I think you should answer this yourself (you have access to more of the details anyway). One other suggestion: you should definitely clear the pip cache to avoid running into similar issues with other modules that have compiled extensions. Usually this lives in `~/.cache/pip/`. There might also a temporary build directory in `/tmp/` ([see here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9510474/1461210)).

Comment: @ali_m I will answer it myself then. You don't get any rep, but thank you for your help anyway. You saved me a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is solved by pip uninstalling numpy (or any other troublesome package), then running

```
pip install numpy --no-cache-dir
```

to prevent pip from simply taking the cached installation and repeating it.

Comment: `--no-cache-dir` did not force a _recompilation_, it just made pip download the package again. `--no-binary :all:` forced a recompilation (running of `setup.py`).

Comment: @Praveen in my case, --no-cache-dir also caused a recompilation (as a consequence of downloading the package again, I guess)

Comment: It's possible that this behaviour varies somewhat from system to system. I've had pip do different things in Ubuntu and Fedora, and also do different things when run in a virtualenv. But `--no-cache-dir` didn't cut it for me :-/

Comment: `--no-cache-dir --force-reinstall` worked for me with pip 23.1.2 on macOS Catalina 10.15.7.

Answer (score 54):

You can use `--no-binary` and `--ignore-installed` to rebuild a package as follows

```
pip install --user --force-reinstall --ignore-installed --no-binary :all: PackageName
```

Comment: `--user` is superfluous here since OP uses virtualenv.

Comment: Regarding `--force-reinstall`, `pip help install` says: "When **upgrading**, reinstall all packages even if they are already up-to-date."

Comment: I have found `--ignore-installed` to cause troubles as it will only install new files, not update existing ones which leaves an inconsistent state. `--force-reinstall` on pip 21 does work as expected

Comment: Note that `:all:` is the argument to `--no-binary`, so the order of the flags matters.