# couldn't install pip in windows

Tags: python, installation, pip

I am trying to install pip in windows.

when i run the get-pip.py file i get the following message:

```
C:\Python27>python get-pip.py

Collecting pip Using cached pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl

Hash of the package https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/p/pip/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=5ff9fec0be479e4e36df467556deed4d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/) (ab1a3864641ecb4ba77b0d30cfdc8442) doesn't match the expected hash 5ff9fec0be479e4e36df467556deed4d!

Bad md5 hash for package https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/p/pip/pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=5ff9fec0be479e4e36df467556deed4d (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/)
```

I don't know what the problem is. can someone help me?

Comment: It looks like the currently cached pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl file does not match the md5 hash of the available pip. I would search your system for pip-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl and delete it, then retry

Comment: @disflux thanks, your comment helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks disflux for your comment that was useful and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510474/removing-pips-cache) post.

I ignored the cache file using the option: `--no-cache-dir`

Now the command looks something like this `C:\Python27>python get-pip.py --no-cache-dir`

Successfully installed pip.

Comment: Glad it helped. Although I don't know why I didn't think of no-cache-dir. Obviously need more coffee yet. ;)