# Cannot upgrade (install latest) version of azure pip module

Tags: python, azure, pip

I try to install latest ([2.0.0rc5](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure/2.0.0rc5)) version of azure pip package, but pip insist to install 1.0.3.

```
# pip install --upgrade azure
Requirement already up-to-date: azure in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
[...]
```

and

```
# pip show azure
---
Metadata-Version: 1.1 
Name: azure
Version: 1.0.3
Summary: Microsoft Azure Client Libraries for Python
[...]
```

but

```
azure (2.0.0rc5)                          - Microsoft Azure Client Libraries for Python
 INSTALLED: 1.0.3
 LATEST:    2.0.0rc5
```

I thought that maybe there is caching problems and tried both suggestion from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510474/removing-pips-cache)

- removing cache directory
- using no cache option

`# pip install --upgrade azure --no-cache-dir
Requirement already up-to-date: azure in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
[...]`

I'm using latest (8.1.2) pip on MacOSX installed with brew.

Answer (score 0):

I found the *pre* option and `pip install --upgrade azure  --pre` works.

`pip show azure
   [...]
Metadata-Version: 2.0
Name: azure
Version: 2.0.0rc5
Summary: Microsoft Azure Client Libraries for Python
[...]`

And Ansible suggestion doesn't (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_azure.html)