# ERROR: torch has an invalid wheel, .dist-info directory not found

Tags: pip, torch

I was going to install torch in virtual environment.
So I commanded !pip install torch, but there was an ERROR.

```
Collecting torch
    Using cached torch-1.7.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl(184.0 MB)
ERROR: torch ahs an invalid wheel, .dist-info directory not found
```

In [How to fix ".dist-info directory not found" in my package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270366/how-to-fix-dist-info-directory-not-found-in-my-package) here, One answer said that deleting Appdata/Local/pip/Cache flder was working.

What should I do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

time has passed. But just in case someone happens to com on this post because of the same issue, you can try the following commands:

If you do not need a CUDA installation

```
pip install torch==1.7.0+cpu torchvision==0.8.1+cpu torchaudio===0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

If you fo need a CUDA installation

```
pip install torch===1.7.0 torchvision===0.8.1 torchaudio===0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

More details about the CUDA version on the official [website](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/)

Comment: Thank you so much! It was an error related to the version of CUDA.
I  have CUDA 10.0, so I should have installed the torch version for it.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the Appdata/Local/pip/Cache folder in a hurry and tried it and it was installed.
Since the deleted folder is still in the Recycle Bin, I decided there would be no problem.

Comment: Holy, after installing, the same error was appeared.........
And it doesn't installed..

Comment: What do you mean by "after installing ... it doesn't installed"?

Comment: @FlyingTeller It's like we are living in the same world, I am facing the same issue right now and earlier when I saw this page your comment wasn't there. I deleted that same Cache folder but its not installing for me

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Try to install a previous version:

```
pip install torch===1.6.0 torchvision===0.7.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I somehow messed up the venv folder (I think it's about pip cache or something), so any try of `pip install -r requirements.txt` failed. I just deleted venv folder and recreated it with `python -m venv venv`

Just after that everything worked as expected and `pip install -r requirements.txt` installed all the packages