# pip install MySQL-python, Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7, pip, mysql-python

## MacOS | Python 2.7

I want to use MySQLdb. When I run

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

The result is

```
JourneydeMacBook-Pro:~ JourneyWoo$ pip install MySQL-python
Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/g9/y4rms8zx6yvjjn1m1w6w0000gn/T/pip-build-JFpAwP/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
    metadata, options = get_config()
      File "setup_posix.py", line 53, in get_config
        libraries = [ dequote(i[2:]) for i in libs if i.startswith(compiler_flag("l")) ]
      File "setup_posix.py", line 8, in dequote
        if s[0] in "\"'" and s[0] == s[-1]:
    IndexError: string index out of range

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/g9/y4rms8zx6yvjjn1m1w6w0000gn/T/pip-build-JFpAwP/MySQL-python/
```

I think my pip got a problem, so I run

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install ez_setup
pip install unroll
```

They all work well, but when I try again

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

It still has the problem.

I did not get the answer which could solve my question and problem from Google Search, really thank you if you could help me with this.

Comment: Try installing in a virtual environment.

Comment: I still cannot solve this question, so I have to give up mysqldb and use pymysql, which is installed by "conda install pymysql"

Comment: It really comes down how you installed MYSQL on your local MAC.   Did you use BREW to install it?  And if so, did you upgrade recently? I ran into similar issue when I ran brew update.   If all of these are true let me know and I can try and help clean that up.

Comment: @JohnnyGasyna yes, but I had updated it and this method did not work...

Comment: @JourneyWoo my question is did you use brew to install MYSQL?  Try this:  sudo pip uninstall mysql-python  then sudo pip install mysql-python

Comment: Also you can try clearing pip's cache, described here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510474/removing-pips-cache

Comment: @JohnnyGasyna Cool man, only uninstall cannot work, but clear can deal with it

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get install python-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev # Debian / Ubuntu 
running this solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

**For linux users**

First install python3-dev by;

```
laptop$sudo apt-get install python3-dev # debian / Ubuntu
laptop$sudo yum install python3-devel # Red Hat / CentOS
laptop$sudo apt-get install mysqlclient
```

If you've previous installation in virtual environment uninstall it, it will also remove MYSQLdb which in my case was the source of all the problem.
Then re-install;

```
   (venv)laptop:~/Desktop/app/$ pip uninstall mysqlclient
    Uninstalling mysqlclient-1.3.13:
     Would remove:
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/*
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_mysql.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_mysql_exceptions.py
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysqlclient-1.3.13-py3.7.egg-info   
   Proceed (y/n)? y
   (venv)laptop:~/Desktop/app/$ pip install mysqlclient
```

More details [here](https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/)