# python install fails "egg_info failed with error code 1". No previous recommendations on similar posts have worked

Tags: python, github, pip

New to python, but I have v. 3.6.3 installed and I'm trying to install an [api from github](https://github.com/jgillick/LendingClub). I type "pip install lendingclub" into the command line and get the error msg:

> "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
>   C:\Users\REDPOI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-adfw3v8o\pybars\"

**I have tried updating pip with the commands :**

```
"pip install --upgrade setuptools"
```

**And**

```
"easy_install -U setuptools"
```

The "pip3 install" gives the same error; I tried that in case the syntax was different for the newer python version. I have the **Environment variables** set to be able to access python from the command line rather than the **anaconda environment**. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am at a loss :/

Comment: did you try to install it offline?

Comment: Sorry to be daft, but how does one go about installing offline?

Comment: Oh, and I also tried "pip install git+https ://github.com/jgillick/LendingClub" also, and I get the same error message.

Comment: Last thing: the output from the command line before the error message is:

  Using cached pybars-0.0.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\REDPOI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-j_whk986\pybars\setup.py", line 22, in <module>
        description = file(
    NameError: name 'file' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

Read these methods :

1. Try to clean your pip and modules caches first, see :
   [Removing pip's cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510474/removing-pips-cache)
2. Try to intall it that current module witthout any caches by this
       command :  **"pip --no-cache-dir install setuptools"**
3. Or try to install it offline, first you need to download that module
       package from github ( prees that "clone or download" green button )
       then extarct that package to some folder, in terminal or cmd try to cd to that
       folder, then use this command : **"python setup.py install"**

Good Luck ...

Comment: Only the third option worked for me, and I had the same issue on Ubuntu.