# Equivalent of brew cleanup in pip

Tags: python, pip

I've been looking around for the equivalent of `brew cleanup` or `npm prune` for **pip** (the package manager for python users), but ain't able to find one.

`cleanup` and `prune` have done me a huge favor of detecting and removing extraneous and outdated packages on Mac, and the closest I get so far for pip is `pip list --outdated --not-required`, which only indicates the outdated and no-longer-required packages.

Does such function exist for pip? or has it already been built in some subcommands of pip? If not, can anyone point me to any third-party script that does this?

Comment: `brew cleanup` removes old versions of packages. Python doesn't allow more than one version of a package to be installed, so what would `pip cleanup` do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31807659/499581