# RuntimeError: PyTorch does not currently provide packages for PyPI

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I'm trying to run  this https://github.com/shariqiqbal2810/MAAC repository and it has a module called `torch`

```
import torch as McLawrence
from torch.autograd import Variable
```

I'm using python version `3.7.1` and I downgraded to `3.6.5` on win10
I tried to use

```
pip install torch
pip install pytorch
pip install torchvision
```

I change `torch` to `pytorch`

I enter their website https://pytorch.org/ and I tried all suggestion that uses `pip` such as

```
pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch-1.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
pip3 install torchvision
```

I read every comment relate to this issue in

https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/566

I read most of the answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=module+named+torch

But I still get the same message:

```
Collecting torch
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/e9/bac4204fe9cb1a002ec6140b47f51affda1655379fe302a1caef421f9846/torch-0.1.2.post1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\iibra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-yupbt_qk\torch\setup.py", line 11, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError(README)
    RuntimeError: PyTorch does not currently provide packages for PyPI (see status at https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/566).

    Please follow the instructions at http://pytorch.org/ to install with miniconda instead.

pip install pytorch
Collecting pytorch
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a9/41/4487bc23e3ac4d674943176f5aa309427b011e00607eb98899e9d951f67b/pytorch-0.1.2.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: pytorch
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pytorch ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\iibra\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\iibra\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-7qwe1571\\pytorch\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\iibra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-_mjh_olk --python-tag cp36:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\iibra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7qwe1571\pytorch\setup.py", line 17, in <module>
      raise Exception(message)
  Exception: You should install pytorch from http://pytorch.org



pip install torchvision
Collecting torchvision
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ca/0d/f00b2885711e08bd71242ebe7b96561e6f6d01fdb4b9dcf4d37e2e13c5e1/torchvision-0.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\iibra\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from torchvision) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow>=4.1.1 in c:\users\iibra\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from torchvision) (5.1.0)
Collecting torch (from torchvision)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/5f/e9/bac4204fe9cb1a002ec6140b47f51affda1655379fe302a1caef421f9846/torch-0.1.2.post1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\iibra\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-k8dl2vhz\torch\setup.py", line 11, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError(README)
    RuntimeError: PyTorch does not currently provide packages for PyPI (see status at https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/566).

    Please follow the instructions at http://pytorch.org/ to install with miniconda instead.
```

Comment: Try this: First, uninstall then clear pip cache then install wheels with `--no-deps` option.

Comment: @harshit_k I tried to `pip cache `
`ERROR: unknown command "cache" - maybe you meant "check"` https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4830 https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4685

Comment: Ya, I meant to remove the cache. Do this: `rm -rf ~/.cache/pip` to remove cache from pip or simply go the folder `.cache` and delete the pip folder. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510474/removing-pips-cache

Comment: You mean `pip/cache`.

Comment: Check the second answer from the link I shared above. The reason I'm saying this is because looking at the errors it seems pip is using cached torch as mentioned https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/566#issuecomment-302721953. Then install pytorch wheels with `--no deps`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked `pip3 --no-cache-dir  install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch-1.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: Great, Also, you can write this as answer and accept it or do you want me to do that?

Comment: @harshit_k you can do it,  I would not be able to solve it without your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing from the PyTorch wheel should have worked. But, the problem turns out to be that `pip` is using the cached pytorch to install it as mentioned on GitHub [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/566#issuecomment-302721953).

```
Collecting pytorch
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages...
```

Either [removing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510474/removing-pips-cache) the pip's cache from `%LocalAppData%\pip\Cache` on Windows or disabling it by using `--no-cache-dir` would solve the issue as follows:

```
pip3 --no-cache-dir install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch-1.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
```

Comment: did it help? its not helping me

Comment: @ERJAN It helps but try to change the link https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu80/torch-1.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl depends on your version from  https://pytorch.org/

Answer (score 2):

For smooth installation of PyTorch, use their options selector, on PyTorch landing page:
[https://pytorch.org/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAwyk.png)
Then copy and run the pip command (or other) according to their suggestion.

[image]

Comment: I mentioned in the question that I already used all the commend that is related to pip.