# How to fix error "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-r1jk6xfr\pandas\"?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, windows-10

I'm trying to install pandas in my windows 10 64bit computer. I already installed python 3.8.0 from the follwing link.

https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

[image: Dowloaded python file]

I tried to install pandas by **pip install pandas** command.
But I couldn't install pandas due to the following error. Can someone help me to solve this error?

[image]

When I tried to install numpy by **pip install numpy** I'm getting the following error.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you installed `numpy` already? If not, please do. Also, why don't you install Anaconda. It has all the necessary libraries built-in.

Comment: I tried to install numpy. But that's also displaying error.

Comment: It requires `MSVC`. Either install it, or try running by clearing cache. Still I suggest leave all this mess and choose [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/).

Comment: I am following a tutorial. That needs pandas to be installed. Do u know how to clear the cache on cmd?

Comment: Refer [Removing pip's cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510474/removing-pips-cache)

Comment: @meW I installed microsoft build tools and then I installed numpy and pandas successfully. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Then I suppose I can add it as a right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the Traceback calls, install the Microsoft Visual C++, followed by the installation of `NumPy` and `Pandas` library.

You or others facing the same problem can also proceed by installing [Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/) which has all the built-in libraries in it.