# zlib.error: Error -5 while decompressing data: incomplete or truncated stream

Tags: python, zlib, torch

While installing torch by `pip install torch` it is throwin the below error

```
Exception:
/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 176, in _loads_v2
    cached = json.loads(zlib.decompress(data).decode("utf8"))
zlib.error: Error -5 while decompressing data: incomplete or truncated stream
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Removing pip's cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510474/removing-pips-cache)

This worked for me

> If using pip 6.0 or newer, try adding the --no-cache-dir option.