# pip errors No files/directories in /tmp/

Tags: python, pip

I am getting `No files/directories in /tmp/*` errors while I try to install any package on my Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS/ Python 3.6.8 / Python 2.7.15+ machine.

For instance,

```
pip install pyx
Collecting pyx
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f7/25/59c136568c1b61ee087155c874fcd9f7196a943a6a5ee3429efeb30ea2a8/PyX-0.15.tar.gz
No files/directories in /tmp/pip-build-nRurCC/pyx/pip-egg-info (from PKG-INFO)
```

This happens for every package I am trying to install.

- `sudo` is not helping.
- Solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510474/removing-pips-cache/9510610#9510610), using `--no-cache-dir option`, is not helping.

Output of running the pip install command with `vvv` option gives the following output.

```
No files/directories in /tmp/pip-build-VU1cex/pyx/pip-egg-info (from PKG-INFO)
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 634, in _prepare_file
    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 129, in prep_for_dist
    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 455, in run_egg_info
    metadata_name = canonicalize_name(self.pkg_info()["Name"])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 533, in pkg_info
    data = self.egg_info_data('PKG-INFO')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 471, in egg_info_data
    filename = self.egg_info_path(filename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 515, in egg_info_path
    'No files/directories in %s (from %s)' % (base, filename)
InstallationError: No files/directories in /tmp/pip-build-VU1cex/pyx/pip-egg-info (from PKG-INFO)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it is an upstream issue I tried multiple things even installing using the latest commit `pip install git+https://github.com/pyx-project/pyx.git@fc66c078727b02693b122ad346b9fa5472e06eb7`, please try this version: `pip install PyX==0.12` it should work.

Comment: Damn. I didn't think of that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If using pip 6.0 or newer, check if it works with the [--no-cache-dir](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#caching) option.

You can also try to get a detailed output from pip using the `-vvv` argument

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9510610/2542835

Comment: I have updated my answer to have a look at the -vvv argument which can tell you more about what is happening when you run the command

Comment: Edited my question which now contains the output when vvv option is used.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `pip3 install x` works for me. `pip install x` does not.