# What are some pip commands to remove excess space stored by pip installation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

Are there pip commands, if any, to remove excessive space caused by pip installations without affecting operations of existing packages?

I am using python 3.7

Comment: What exactly do you expect to be removed?

Comment: Perhaps some cache which serve no useful purpose.

Comment: The cache serves very useful purpose: it caches downloaded packages and generated wheel files so every time you create a new Python virtual environment you don't need to download and rebuild those packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cleaning up cache is not built in `pip` command. You have to clean the cache folder manually.

> The default location for the cache directory depends on the Operating System:
>
> Unix
>   `~/.cache/pip` and it respects the `XDG_CACHE_HOME` directory.
>
> macOS
>   `~/Library/Caches/pip`.
>
> Windows
>   `<CSIDL_LOCAL_APPDATA>\pip\Cache`

For example,

```sh
# clean up cache on Linux
rm -rf ~/.cache/pip
```

References

- [`pip install`: Caching](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#id40)

Answer (score 12):

As of pip 20.1, you can just use `pip cache purge`
Check one of the pip maintainers' SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61762308/13184911).