Where does python store downloaded whl packages when using venv
I ran a command to try to install tensorflow pip install tensorflow[and-cuda]
I don't now why, but it started downloading every version of tensorflow available.
I stopped it before it finished, but I would like to get my hard drive space back.
Where can I find these WHL packages, and delete them?
I am using a venv, and it is activated, but I do not see them in the venv folder, and I did not see the size of the venv folder grow as I installed these packages. They must be temporarily stored somewhere else before being installed.
Thanks
  Downloading tensorflow-2.16.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (2.1 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-intel==2.16.1
  Downloading tensorflow_intel-2.16.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (376.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 376.9 MB 23 kB/s
Collecting nvidia-cudnn-cu12==8.9.7.29
  Downloading nvidia_cudnn_cu12-8.9.7.29-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (719.4 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 719.4 MB 1.3 kB/s
Collecting nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12==12.3.101
  Downloading nvidia_cuda_cupti_cu12-12.3.101-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (10.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 10.0 MB 3.3 MB/s
Collecting nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12==12.3.107
  Downloading nvidia_cuda_nvrtc_cu12-12.3.107-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (20.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 20.1 MB 21 kB/s
Collecting nvidia-cusolver-cu12==11.5.4.101
  Downloading nvidia_cusolver_cu12-11.5.4.101-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (122.5 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 122.5 MB 50 kB/s
Collecting nvidia-cublas-cu12==12.3.4.1
  Downloading nvidia_cublas_cu12-12.3.4.1-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (446.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 446.2 MB 14 kB/s
Collecting nvidia-cuda-nvcc-cu12==12.3.107
  Downloading nvidia_cuda_nvcc_cu12-12.3.107-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (16.4 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 16.4 MB 3.3 MB/s
Collecting nvidia-cusparse-cu12==12.2.0.103
  Downloading nvidia_cusparse_cu12-12.2.0.103-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (194.4 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 194.4 MB 3.2 kB/s
Collecting nvidia-cufft-cu12==11.0.12.1
  Downloading nvidia_cufft_cu12-11.0.12.1-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (97.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 97.8 MB 145 kB/s
Collecting nvidia-curand-cu12==10.3.4.107
  Downloading nvidia_curand_cu12-10.3.4.107-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (55.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 55.8 MB 3.2 MB/s
Collecting tensorflow[and-cuda]
  Downloading tensorflow-2.15.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (2.1 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-intel==2.15.1
  Downloading tensorflow_intel-2.15.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (300.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 300.9 MB 1.2 kB/s
Collecting nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12==12.2.140
  Downloading nvidia_cuda_runtime_cu12-12.2.140-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (842 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 842 kB 6.4 MB/s
Collecting nvidia-cufft-cu12==11.0.8.103
  Downloading nvidia_cufft_cu12-11.0.8.103-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (99.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 99.0 MB 16 kB/s
Collecting tensorflow[and-cuda]
  Downloading tensorflow-2.15.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (2.1 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-intel==2.15.0
  Downloading tensorflow_intel-2.15.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (300.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 300.9 MB 1.6 kB/s
Collecting tensorflow[and-cuda]
  Downloading tensorflow-2.14.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (2.1 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-intel==2.14.1
  Downloading tensorflow_intel-2.14.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (284.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 284.1 MB 7.5 kB/s
Collecting nvidia-cufft-cu11==10.9.0.58
  Downloading nvidia_cufft_cu11-10.9.0.58-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (172.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 172.2 MB 1.5 kB/s
Collecting nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu11==11.8.89
  Downloading nvidia_cuda_runtime_cu11-11.8.89-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (1.0 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.0 MB 3.3 MB/s
Collecting nvidia-cuda-nvcc-cu11==11.8.89
  Downloading nvidia_cuda_nvcc_cu11-11.8.89-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (15.7 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 15.7 MB 3.3 MB/s
Collecting nvidia-cusolver-cu11==11.4.1.48
  Downloading nvidia_cusolver_cu11-11.4.1.48-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (125.7 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 125.7 MB 57 kB/s
Collecting tensorflow[and-cuda]
  Downloading tensorflow-2.14.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (2.1 kB)
Collecting tensorflow-intel==2.14.0
  Downloading tensorflow_intel-2.14.0-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (284.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 284.1 MB 3.6 kB/s
Collecting tensorflow[and-cuda]
  Downloading tensorflow-2.13.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (1.9 kB)
WARNING: tensorflow 2.13.1 does not provide the extra 'and-cuda'
Collecting tensorflow-intel==2.13.1
  Downloading tensorflow_intel-2.13.1-cp310-cp310-win_amd64.whl (276.5 MB)


https://stackoverflow.com/a/70394881/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+clean+cache
