# Installing pygame though pip but I keep getting an error

Tags: python, windows, pip, pygame

I am trying to install pygame on windows 10 using pip. I am using python 3. I keep getting this error when I run `pip install pygame`:

```
Collecting pygame
  Using cached pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\aarav\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\aarav\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4b04m745\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\aarav\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4b04m745\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\aarav\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-up4741kz'
         cwd: C:\Users\aarav\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4b04m745\pygame\
    Complete output (17 lines):


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...


    Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x64"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\aarav\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4b04m745\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "C:\Users\aarav\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4b04m745\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "C:\Users\aarav\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4b04m745\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
        and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
      File "C:\Users\aarav\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4b04m745\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
        reply = raw_input(
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can fix this?

Comment: Do you need that version specifically? It isn't current. Did you try removing the .tar.gz file and trying again?

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510474/removing-pips-cache helps?

Comment: So `pip install pygame --no-cache-dir`? I don't need that version specifically, but I don't know which version the new one is

Comment: To the close voters, the linked answers are largely unhelpful or incorrect.

Answer (score 4):

From your error logs, you're using Python 3.9. The current Pygame release, 1.9.6 doesn't [support](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/2145) Python 3.9. You have several options:

1. Install and use Python 3.8, then `pip install pygame` should work.
2. Install the Pygame 2 development version, `pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev14`, or `pip install pygame --pre` to obtain the latest pre-release version.
3. Try a third party [pygame wheel](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame) from Christoph Gohlke, he offers pygame 1.9.6 linked against cpython39.