# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output

Tags: python, pip, pygame

I try to run this in CMD
`pip install pygame`

Full Error

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\sivan\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\sivan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dz1zm4zn\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\sivan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dz1zm4zn\\pygame\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\sivan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-_w5pcpwc'
         cwd: C:\Users\sivan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dz1zm4zn\pygame\
    Complete output (17 lines):


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...
```

Removed some part of the error.

```
      File "C:\Users\sivan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dz1zm4zn\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
        reply = raw_input(
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

What is the problem here ?
Please explain

Comment: which python version r u using?

Comment: python version 3.9.0, pip version 20.2.4

Comment: r u trying to install pygame?

Comment: Pygame does not currently support Python 3.9. For options, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64412994/7675174) or try `pip install pygame --pre` for the latest development version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing pygame though pip but I keep getting an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64412994/installing-pygame-though-pip-but-i-keep-getting-an-error)

Comment: Thank you for the help @importrandom that makes sense .

Comment: @CYREX yes I am, i recently updated to python 3.9.0 and didn't realize that pygame didnt work with python 3.9.0 yet, thanks for the help