# errror is coming while installing pygame

Tags: python, installation, pygame

i installed pygame with the following command

pip install pygame

and the output error was

Collecting pygame
Using cached pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\users\meera\python3.9\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Meera\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a1j98e3y\pygame\setup.py'"'"'; **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Meera\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a1j98e3y\pygame\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\Meera\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-3ztgshzy'
cwd: C:\Users\Meera\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a1j98e3y\pygame
Complete output (17 lines):

```
WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
Using WINDOWS configuration...


Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x64"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Meera\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a1j98e3y\pygame\setup.py", line 194, in <module>
    buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
  File "C:\Users\Meera\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a1j98e3y\pygame\buildconfig\config.py", line 210, in main
    deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Meera\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a1j98e3y\pygame\buildconfig\config_win.py", line 576, in main
    and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
  File "C:\Users\Meera\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-a1j98e3y\pygame\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py", line 302, in ask
    reply = raw_input(
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing pygame though pip but I keep getting an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64412994/installing-pygame-though-pip-but-i-keep-getting-an-error)

Answer (score 1):

In the Command Prompt / Terminal type `pip install pygame==2.0.0.dev6`

Comment: same error is coming again  @abhigyan jaiswal