# Pygame missing quit module

Tags: python, pygame

Whenever I try to run `event.type == pygame.QUIT`, `event.type == QUIT`
or `event.type == pygame.quit()` in my pygame program, I get an error saying that `Module 'pygame' has no 'QUIT' member` or `Undefined variable 'QUIT'`. When I run the program, it opens just fine but when I close out of the pygame window, it crashes completely and doesn't close.

I have tried to reinstall pygame but that didn't work. It seems like the pygame package has no quit function of any kind, even though the other functions like `Clock()` and `display()` are there. I think that it might have to do with installation issues, but I don't know how to address that in a concise way.

Here's my code:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
from sys import exit
import os
from moves import Moves
from moves import *
from character import Character
from items import Items
import random
import pandas as pd
from pokemon import Pokemon
...


running = True
FPS = 60
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while running:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            running=False
```

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Maybe you overwrote `pygame` with something in your code? That's just a wild guess since it's actually impossible to help without seeing your code. Post a [mre] please.

Comment: Reinstalling pygame through pip is likely going to install the same one with issues as it is cached. I had the same problem a while back. Try using `pip install --no-cache-dir < pygame >`.  Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510474/removing-pips-cache)

Comment: @hippozhipos, I tried the pip install command and it says requirement already satisfied, should I uninstall and reinstall this way?

Comment: updated with code @BWallDev

Comment: @synarchy yea do `pip uninstall pygame` first and then do the fresh install without cache

Comment: @hippozhipos i tried the no cache install but nothing changed :(

Comment: @synarchy Can you post a [mcve]? Remove all the unnecessary imports so the code can be run by us, and then confirm that you can run the code you've posted and verify that the problem still exists. Also, please provide the version of pygame and python.

Comment: Have you tried doing it object oriented? By that saying, I mean, putting code inside functions.

Comment: @L.Papadopoulos That would not help the problem. Using different programming paradigms don't effect undefined variables or other errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try import pygame.locals with:

```
from pygame.locals import *
```

I had the same problem several times and this fixed it for me. Just add it to your import section **additionally** to your normal pygame import.

Comment: That does not seem to be the issue since the OP mentioned he tried `pygame.QUIT` as well and not just `QUIT`

Comment: Yeah, I tried this already and unfortunately it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

is the ' symbol in your code before the import or was that accidentally placed there when copying your code?

```
`import pygame, sys
```

You're right, to check if the user wants to close the window it should be:

```
event.type == pygame.QUIT
```

Also, try adding this in the beginning of your code after your imports:

```
pygame.init()
```

Not sure if those will fix, but give it a shot

Comment: yeah that was just markup. I tried the init but that didn't work either. This is so frustrating! is it possible I just have an old version of pygame? How could a function be excluded like this?

Answer (score 0):

> This is more of a workaround than anything else, as it is often much better to install the module properly than to do something like this

`pygame.QUIT`, as with nearly any other pygame, or SDL constant, just returns a number. define pygame's constants for yourself:

```
ACTIVEEVENT 1
ANYFORMAT 268435456
ASYNCBLIT 4
AUDIODEVICEADDED -1
AUDIODEVICEREMOVED -1
AUDIO_ALLOW_ANY_CHANGE -1
AUDIO_ALLOW_CHANNELS_CHANGE -1
AUDIO_ALLOW_FORMAT_CHANGE -1
AUDIO_ALLOW_FREQUENCY_CHANGE -1
AUDIO_S16 32784
AUDIO_S16LSB 32784
AUDIO_S16MSB 36880
AUDIO_S16SYS 32784
AUDIO_S8 32776
AUDIO_U16 16
AUDIO_U16LSB 16
AUDIO_U16MSB 4112
AUDIO_U16SYS 16
AUDIO_U8 8
BIG_ENDIAN 4321
BLEND_ADD 1
BLEND_MAX 5
BLEND_MIN 4
BLEND_MULT 3
BLEND_PREMULTIPLIED 17
BLEND_RGBA_ADD 6
BLEND_RGBA_MAX 16
BLEND_RGBA_MIN 9
BLEND_RGBA_MULT 8
BLEND_RGBA_SUB 7
BLEND_RGB_ADD 1
BLEND_RGB_MAX 5
BLEND_RGB_MIN 4
BLEND_RGB_MULT 3
BLEND_RGB_SUB 2
BLEND_SUB 2
BUTTON_LEFT 1
BUTTON_MIDDLE 2
BUTTON_RIGHT 3
BUTTON_WHEELDOWN 5
BUTTON_WHEELUP 4
BUTTON_X1 6
BUTTON_X2 7
DOUBLEBUF 1073741824
DROPBEGIN -1
DROPCOMPLETE -1
DROPFILE -1
DROPTEXT -1
FINGERDOWN -1
FINGERMOTION -1
FINGERUP -1
FULLSCREEN -2147483648
GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL 15
GL_ACCUM_ALPHA_SIZE 11
GL_ACCUM_BLUE_SIZE 10
GL_ACCUM_GREEN_SIZE 9
GL_ACCUM_RED_SIZE 8
GL_ALPHA_SIZE 3
GL_BLUE_SIZE 2
GL_BUFFER_SIZE 4
GL_DEPTH_SIZE 6
GL_DOUBLEBUFFER 5
GL_GREEN_SIZE 1
GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS 13
GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES 14
GL_RED_SIZE 0
GL_STENCIL_SIZE 7
GL_STEREO 12
GL_SWAP_CONTROL 16
HAT_CENTERED 0
HAT_DOWN 4
HAT_LEFT 8
HAT_LEFTDOWN 12
HAT_LEFTUP 9
HAT_RIGHT 2
HAT_RIGHTDOWN 6
HAT_RIGHTUP 3
HAT_UP 1
HWACCEL 256
HWPALETTE 536870912
HWSURFACE 1
IYUV_OVERLAY 1448433993
JOYAXISMOTION 7
JOYBALLMOTION 8
JOYBUTTONDOWN 10
JOYBUTTONUP 11
JOYHATMOTION 9
KEYDOWN 2
KEYUP 3
KMOD_ALT 768
KMOD_CAPS 8192
KMOD_CTRL 192
KMOD_LALT 256
KMOD_LCTRL 64
KMOD_LMETA 1024
KMOD_LSHIFT 1
KMOD_META 3072
KMOD_MODE 16384
KMOD_NONE 0
KMOD_NUM 4096
KMOD_RALT 512
KMOD_RCTRL 128
KMOD_RMETA 2048
KMOD_RSHIFT 2
KMOD_SHIFT 3
K_0 48
K_1 49
K_2 50
K_3 51
K_4 52
K_5 53
K_6 54
K_7 55
K_8 56
K_9 57
K_AMPERSAND 38
K_ASTERISK 42
K_AT 64
K_BACKQUOTE 96
K_BACKSLASH 92
K_BACKSPACE 8
K_BREAK 318
K_CAPSLOCK 301
K_CARET 94
K_CLEAR 12
K_COLON 58
K_COMMA 44
K_DELETE 127
K_DOLLAR 36
K_DOWN 274
K_END 279
K_EQUALS 61
K_ESCAPE 27
K_EURO 321
K_EXCLAIM 33
K_F1 282
K_F10 291
K_F11 292
K_F12 293
K_F13 294
K_F14 295
K_F15 296
K_F2 283
K_F3 284
K_F4 285
K_F5 286
K_F6 287
K_F7 288
K_F8 289
K_F9 290
K_FIRST 0
K_GREATER 62
K_HASH 35
K_HELP 315
K_HOME 278
K_INSERT 277
K_KP0 256
K_KP1 257
K_KP2 258
K_KP3 259
K_KP4 260
K_KP5 261
K_KP6 262
K_KP7 263
K_KP8 264
K_KP9 265
K_KP_DIVIDE 267
K_KP_ENTER 271
K_KP_EQUALS 272
K_KP_MINUS 269
K_KP_MULTIPLY 268
K_KP_PERIOD 266
K_KP_PLUS 270
K_LALT 308
K_LAST 323
K_LCTRL 306
K_LEFT 276
K_LEFTBRACKET 91
K_LEFTPAREN 40
K_LESS 60
K_LMETA 310
K_LSHIFT 304
K_LSUPER 311
K_MENU 319
K_MINUS 45
K_MODE 313
K_NUMLOCK 300
K_PAGEDOWN 281
K_PAGEUP 280
K_PAUSE 19
K_PERIOD 46
K_PLUS 43
K_POWER 320
K_PRINT 316
K_QUESTION 63
K_QUOTE 39
K_QUOTEDBL 34
K_RALT 307
K_RCTRL 305
K_RETURN 13
K_RIGHT 275
K_RIGHTBRACKET 93
K_RIGHTPAREN 41
K_RMETA 309
K_RSHIFT 303
K_RSUPER 312
K_SCROLLOCK 302
K_SEMICOLON 59
K_SLASH 47
K_SPACE 32
K_SYSREQ 317
K_TAB 9
K_UNDERSCORE 95
K_UNKNOWN 0
K_UP 273
K_a 97
K_b 98
K_c 99
K_d 100
K_e 101
K_f 102
K_g 103
K_h 104
K_i 105
K_j 106
K_k 107
K_l 108
K_m 109
K_n 110
K_o 111
K_p 112
K_q 113
K_r 114
K_s 115
K_t 116
K_u 117
K_v 118
K_w 119
K_x 120
K_y 121
K_z 122
LIL_ENDIAN 1234
MOUSEBUTTONDOWN 5
MOUSEBUTTONUP 6
MOUSEMOTION 4
MOUSEWHEEL -1
MULTIGESTURE -1
NOEVENT 0
NOFRAME 32
NUMEVENTS 32
OPENGL 2
OPENGLBLIT 10
PREALLOC 16777216
QUIT 12
RESIZABLE 16
RLEACCEL 16384
RLEACCELOK 8192
SCRAP_BMP image/bmp
SCRAP_CLIPBOARD 0
SCRAP_PBM image/pbm
SCRAP_PPM image/ppm
SCRAP_SELECTION 1
SCRAP_TEXT text/plain
SRCALPHA 65536
SRCCOLORKEY 4096
SWSURFACE 0
SYSWMEVENT 13
TEXTEDITING -1
TEXTINPUT -1
TIMER_RESOLUTION 10
USEREVENT 24
USEREVENT_DROPFILE 4096
UYVY_OVERLAY 1498831189
VIDEOEXPOSE 17
VIDEORESIZE 16
WINDOWEVENT -1
WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE -1
YUY2_OVERLAY 844715353
YV12_OVERLAY 842094169
YVYU_OVERLAY 1431918169
```