# Clear Cygwin Cache

Tags: python, build, cygwin

How can I clear the Cygwin cache, or whatever cache is being used, so that it does not search for files from previous builds?

For example, I get the following error, when I run python3 -m pip install osmium, from Cygwin shell... because I deleted the file, as I don't want it to be used.

...

> CMake Error at cmake/FindOsmium.cmake:76 (message):
> Missing
> C:/Files/osmium-3.1.3/contrib/libosmium/include/osmium/version.hpp.
> Either your libosmium version is too old, or libosmium wasn't found in the
> place you said.   Call Stack (most recent call first):

...

I want to start with a clean slate, so that the package is newly downloaded, but the cache is being searched, and looking to use what's there.
I realize it does not even acknowledge that I have change the path on an environment variable, but looks for the previous.

Is there a file I need to edit, to start clean, or is there a command that wipes the slate clean, so to speak?

Comment: have you installed the cygwin cmake ?

Comment: I installed the cmake package with cygwin.

Comment: So it's the cmake cache that needs clearing. I didn't think about that.
I just looked to the right, and saw this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510474/removing-pips-cache?rq=1
That works for pip, so now I realize that osmium contains libosmium which requires cmake to build it. 
I'll try building libosmium then.