# Launching Pip3 install package_name on macOS

Tags: macos, pip, homebrew, xcode-command-line-tools

I have installed homebrew this morning and I added the path in `/Users/$USER/.homebrew/bin` since this is the correct path for those who care about folder permissions in `/usr/local`

Taken from these sources:

1. [applehelpwriter, which has been taken down lately](https://web.archive.org/web/20210228052302/https://applehelpwriter.com/2018/03/21/how-homebrew-invites-users-to-get-pwned)
2. [THN post](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12892929)

Now I launched `pip3 install moodle-dl` but the default path was first `/usr/bin/pip3` where command line tools were installed and it failed since the `pip3` version from `python 3.8.9` was not up to date.

Since I changed the default `$PATH` in my `.zshrc` with:

```
export PATH=/Users/$USER/.homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I managed to solve the issue, with the `bin` folder inside `~/.homebrew/bin` served first, but I'd like to find and purge all the binaries/caches which were used by the default `pip3` which came along with the `Command Line tools for Xcode`.

So far, I've only found that `pip3` from `/usr/bin/pip3` wrote to `/Users/$USER/Library/Caches/pip` and to `/Users/$USER/Library/Python`, is there any other directory that I'm unaware of? Are there some `man` pages which explain what directories are touched by the `Command line tools for Xcode`?

If you've read so far, thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try pip itself to clear things out.

See examples and usage: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61762308/1931274 (h/t to [pradyunsg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1931274/pradyunsg) in their [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510474/pip-uses-incorrect-cached-package-version-instead-of-the-user-specified-version#comment109248023_9510474) on another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510474/pip-uses-incorrect-cached-package-version-instead-of-the-user-specified-version))

Just be sure to use pip3 under /usr/bin