# How to prevent pip from installing a package if it has been installed by conda already

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I'm experimenting with my python package. I use anaconda and, inside my environment, I have packages that I need already installed:

`conda list | egrep "rdkit|numpy"`
returns

```
numpy                     1.19.2           py39h89c1606_0  
numpy-base                1.19.2           py39h2ae0177_0  
rdkit                     2022.03.1b1.0    py39he30056e_1    rdkit/label/beta
```

My setup.py has two dependencies without specifying versions:

```
install_requires=[
    'rdkit',
    'numpy',
],
```

But when I run `pip install .` it installs another version of rdkit

```
Collecting rdkit
  Using cached rdkit-2022.3.4-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (22.9 MB)
```

The question is, how to prevent pip from such behavior? I want something like: if a package has already been installed, whatever the version, just keep it and do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
pip install --no-cache-dir
```

to avoid cached versions.

Check this link, it might have what you need:

[pip uses incorrect cached package version, instead of the user-specified version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510474/pip-uses-incorrect-cached-package-version-instead-of-the-user-specified-version)